# Android Soundpool loaded in onCreate causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, soundpool

EDIT:  Added setOnLoadCompleteListener as requested, as well as loaded checks.  Still get the same null pointer crash even though the

I have six sound effects that I am loading into a soundpool during onCreate.  When I try to play these sounds, the app crashes and I get a NullPointerException.  I have gone through many questions and tutorials and I just can't figure out what's wrong.  I have cleaned the project, restarted Eclipse as well.  I know these sound files work because I had them running as mediaplayers before and they were fine, but I wanted to put them in a more appropriate soundpool.

It would be a great help if someone could point out the mistake I have made.  Any more information needed will be added if necessary.  Thank you for your time!

Relevant portions of code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SoundPool sp;
boolean loaded = false;

int dicesoundId;
int gunfire1soundId;
int smacksoundId;
int cellardoorsoundId;
int grenadesoundId;
int pageturn3soundId;
```

The onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      sp = new SoundPool(9, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
      sp.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                         if (status == 0){
                            loaded = true;
                         }
                        }
                    });

      dicesoundId = sp.load(this, R.raw.dice, 1);
      gunfire1soundId = sp.load(this, R.raw.gunfire1, 1);
      smacksoundId = sp.load(this, R.raw.smack, 1);
      cellardoorsoundId = sp.load(this, R.raw.cellardoor, 1);
      grenadesoundId = sp.load(this, R.raw.grenade, 1);
      pageturn3soundId = sp.load(this, R.raw.pageturn3, 1);
```

An example of one of the places that causes the nullpointerexception:

```
menuButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (musicOn == 1 && loaded) sp.play(pageturn3soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            loadPage(button1link);}

        }
    });
```

musicOn is set to on unless the user toggles it off.  The crash only happens when the music is toggled on.

Weirdly, even my onPause causes the app to crash:

```
    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (musicOn == 1 && loaded) {
        sp.release();
        sp = null;
    }
}
```

The LogCat from when the app last crashed when entering onPause:

```
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855): Process: com.greekwinterproductions.westwarddystopia, PID: 4855
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.--cut---.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3003)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2981)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at com.greekwinterproductions.westwarddystopia.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:3122)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5335)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1233)
01-15 18:37:54.823: E/AndroidRuntime(4855):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3034)

Comment: can you try
    `if (musicOn == 1 && sp!=null)`
as your if statement in `onClick`
and similarly, a null check for `sp.release();`

Comment: Interesting.  As you likely expected, adding those checks prevents the crash.  Why would sp be null?

Answer (score 1):

SoundPool constructor is deprecated now,, using this sampl code instead

```
AudioAttributes attr = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .build();

pool = new SoundPool.Builder().setAudioAttributes(attr).setMaxStreams(6).build();
```

here is the documentation of API

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.Builder.html

Comment: Added this and updated my code above.  Checking for a successful load returns true and the app still crashes any time a sound is played from that soundpool.  If I replace the loaded check with a sp!=null check before playing the sound, the app does not crash and does not play the sound, seeming to indicate that the soundpool is somehow becoming null before I get to use it.  As I make no calls to the soundpool before this initial sound effect, and certainly do not release it, is there any possible reason that this could happen?

Comment: SoundPool constructor is deprecated now, using this sampl code instead @regomar

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve your problem, regomar? I had a similar issue and what I did is, 
I added a line to my Class definition

> protected    SoundPool  sndPool;

then I load several sounds in OnCreate into this sndPool object,

I also define in the Class

> protected int bgsound1;
>   protected int bgsound2;
>   protected int bgsound3;

to use as references to specific sounds
 Then in my UI thread I can make call to sndPool with my specific bgsound and it works fine.